# how to refer to a perl module whose name would be passed at run time?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is it possible to refer to a perl module whose name would be passed as a command line argument?

I can do `use $ARGV[0]` to get the module but how do i refer to anything imported by `EXPORT_OK` in the module?

Comment: Also see the [`-M` switch in perlrun](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlrun#-m[-]module) switch to specify a module to load from the command line.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This actually is a good question.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I don't know why either, but the [tag:perl] tag is one of the most consistently negative places on SO.

Answer (score 1):

[UNIVERSAL::require](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL::require) is made for this purpose only.

**Description:** `require()` modules from a variable

**Snippet:**

```
require UNIVERSAL::require;

my $module = $ARGV[0];
$module->require or die $@;

my $require_return = $module->use(@imports) or die $@;
```

Comment: But that's at run time, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, dynamically-loaded modules are loaded at run-time, so one would use one of the following:

```
my $module_path = $module_name;
$module_path =~ s{::}{/}g;
$module_path .= '.pm';
require $module_path;
```

or

```
$module_name !~ /^\w+(?:::\w+)*\z/
   or die("Bad module name\n");

eval("use $module_name qw( ); 1")
   or die $@;
```

These don't import, since it doesn't make much sense to import at run-time. You want to import from the modules, which mean you really want to load the module at compile-time. The following is a convenient trick:

```
use if 1, $module_name, @imports;
```

You could also use either of the following:

```
BEGIN {
   my $module_path = $module_name;
   $module_path =~ s{::}{/}g;
   $module_path .= '.pm';
   require $module_path;
   import $module_name @imports;
}
```

or

```
BEGIN {
   $module_name !~ /^\w+(?:::\w+)*\z/
      or die("Bad module name\n");

   eval("use $module_name \@imports; 1")
      or die $@;
}
```

There are modules that can also help.